# Xpath expression for searching multiple tags in a single expression

Tags: xml, xpath

I have follwoing XML Example -

```
    <World>
    <Continents>
    <Continent>America</Continent>
    <Cities>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <City>New York</City>
    </Cities>
    <Description>Newyork is a nice city</Description>
    <Cities>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <City>Philadelphia</City>
    </Cities>
    <Description>Philadelphia is a nice city</Description>
    <Cities>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <City>New Orleans</City>
    </Cities>
    <Description>New Orleans is a nice city</Description>
    </Continents>
    <Continents>
    <Continent>Asia</Continent>
    <Cities>
            <Country>India</Country>
            <City>Mumbai</City>
    </Cities>
    <Description>Mumbai is a nice city</Description>
    <Cities>
            <Country>India</Country>
            <City>New Delhi</City>
    </Cities>
    <Description>New Delhi is a nice city</Description>
    <Cities>
            <Country>India</Country>
            <City>Kolkata</City>
    </Cities>
    <Description>Kolkata is a nice city</Description>
    <Cities>
            <Country>Japan</Country>
            <City>Tokyo</City>
    </Cities>
    <Description>Tokyo is a nice city</Description>
    </Continents>
    </World>
```

I want to list Description for following condition -

```
 Country="India" OR City="New York"
 Continent="Asia" OR Country="Japan"
```

Comment: Please complete your question title and show us what you've tried. If you've not tried anything, try something.

Comment: Also please read the [faq] and [ask] before posting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next one:

```
//Description[
  (preceding-sibling::Cities[1]/Country = "India" or 
   preceding-sibling::Cities[1]/City = "New York"
  ) or 
  (preceding-sibling::Continent[1] = "Asia" or 
   preceding-sibling::Cities[1]/Country = "Japan"
  )
]
```

Output in my test (`--NODE--` is a literal text added by my tool):

```
<Description>Newyork is a nice city</Description>-- NODE --
<Description>Mumbai is a nice city</Description>-- NODE --
<Description>New Delhi is a nice city</Description>-- NODE --
<Description>Kolkata is a nice city</Description>-- NODE --
<Description>Tokyo is a nice city</Description>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...again... I made respective changes for OR and AND usage..Thanks a lot again :) And the answer was worth losing 2 pts. ;)